# How to make an element become fixed when 50px from the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html div element that scrolls with the page but I would like it to become fixed once it reaches 50px from the top of the screen...
How is this done?
My div id is #box
Thanks!
-Ina

Comment: Try searching for some JavaScript libraries or tutorials

Comment: @Ina doesn't my answer work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35953045/2813224

Comment: sorry for the downvote - but this question is very easily researched and has a number of available answers. You need to research for options to use BEFORE you ask the question here.

Comment: @gavgrif I have researched and tried every answer that I could find but nothing is working- even when I copy and paste the same code that people are answering with!

Comment: @zer00ne I've tried but no solutions I've found so far (including yours) have worked...

Comment: @Ina updated answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35953045/2813224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be fixed at the top of the page at some distance from the top, you can check the top offset of the element and change the class when it reach the distance you want.

Here is the jquery code for your reference

```
 jQuery(document).scroll(function() {

        var documentTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
        console.log('this is current top of your document' + documentTop );
        //box top is 891
        if (documentTop > 841) {
            //change the value of the css at this point
            jQuery("#box").addClass("stayfix");
        }
        else        
        {
            jQuery("#box").removeClass("stayfix");
        }

});
```

You need to be more specific about what have you done so far. For eg, how did you make the div element to scrolls inside the page. using css or js/jquery animation features?That will help us to give more specific answer.

**Edited According to your fiddle.

Comment: I can't get this to work. The navbarInitialTop does not change on scrolling.

Comment: give me fiddle, I will check it for you.

Comment: @YoYo Here is a link to a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ina_/aw3gcajb/ Any help would be much appreciated as I've tried every answer that I can find on the web but nothing has worked !

Comment: @Ina check this link https://jsfiddle.net/aw3gcajb/4/ . Your problem was, it is not your box that scroll. It stay normal when your document scroll. So we need to check the current top of document. Not box's. And when this document scroll reach at the height you want, change the class of the box.

Comment: @YoYo Thankyou so much! How do I find the current top of my document though?

Comment: do you mean how to view the documentTop variable that i added on the console? just open the chrome browser and right-click inspect. Then go to Console menu.

Answer (score 0):

They are right, this question is duplicate. Here is a code I made with answers from the forum.

```
var box_top = $("#box").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (box_top - 50)) {
    $("#box").css({position:"fixed",top:"50px"});
  } else {
    $("#box").css({position:"relative"});   
  }
});
```

Hope it helps anyway.

https://jsfiddle.net/ay54msd5/1/

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. It's a solution using jquery (hopefully not a problem) that checks the scrollHeight of the page every time the page scrolls. If the scrollHeight is greater than a certain threshold, the element becomes fixed. If not, the element is positioned relatively (but you can do whatever you want in that case.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navFixed = false;
  var $box = $("#box");
  var topHeight = 50;

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= topHeight && !navFixed) {
      $box.css("position", "fixed");
      navFixed = true;
    }
    else if ($(document).scrollTop() < topHeight && navFixed) {
      $box.css("position", "relative");
      navFixed = false;
    }
  });
});
```

You would have to write some additional CSS targeting the `#box` element that tells it what coordinates you'd like it to be fixed to.

Comment: Because you have to take in mind the offset of the #box div before add the fixed position. Here a fiddle of your code : https://jsfiddle.net/LezLa8eh/
Also, because... I'm jalous, I want the same hat ! ; )